# Unity C# - for loop: go from one object to the next one (movement) - gets stuck on first object

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine

**What I have**

Scenario where a sphere moves towards a cube. There are multiple cubes. I want it to go to 1 cube that is within sight, and when it reached the cube, I want it to search for the next one. I know this should be easy but I've tried to fix this for several hours.

**Code**

**WithinSight.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using BehaviorDesigner.Runtime;
using BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Tasks;

public class WithinSight : Conditional {

    public float fieldOfViewAngle;
    public string targetTag;
    public SharedTransform target;

    private Transform[] possibleTargets;

    public override void OnAwake() {
        var targets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag (targetTag);
        possibleTargets = new Transform[targets.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < targets.Length; ++i) {
            possibleTargets [i] = targets [i].transform;
        }
    }


    public override TaskStatus OnUpdate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < possibleTargets.Length; ++i) {
            if (withinSight(possibleTargets [i], fieldOfViewAngle)) {
                target.Value = possibleTargets [i];
                return TaskStatus.Success;
                gameObject.tag = "Untagged";
            }
        }
        return TaskStatus.Failure;
    }



    public bool withinSight(Transform targetTransform, float fieldOfViewAngle) {
        Vector3 direction = targetTransform.position - transform.position;
        return Vector3.Angle(direction, transform.forward) < fieldOfViewAngle;
    }

}
```

**MoveTowards.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using BehaviorDesigner.Runtime;
using BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Tasks;

public class MoveTowards : Action {

    public float speed = 0;
    public SharedTransform target;
    private bool pietje;

    void PrintMessage (string message) {
        Debug.Log(message);
    }

    void Start() {
        pietje = false;
    }

    public override TaskStatus OnUpdate() {

        if (Vector3.SqrMagnitude (transform.position - target.Value.position) < 0.1f && !pietje) {
            PrintMessage ("Found the cube.");
            pietje = true;
            if (pietje) {
                PrintMessage ("Searching...");
                pietje = false;
            }
            return TaskStatus.Success;
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, target.Value.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.LookAt (target.Value.position);
        return TaskStatus.Running;

    }
}
```

Anyone that can help me will get a virtual cookie! (hmmm...)

Comment: Anyone that knows a possible solution?

Comment: What is the reason for this code: `pietje = true; if (pietje) {...}` ?

Comment: Your code seems far too complicated for what you are trying to achieve:
1. Find all target objects, save them in array (you got that.)
2. Loop through the array subtracting each pair of vectors untill you found the closest, 
3. Move to the position using Vector3.Lerp, or Vector 3.MoveTo
4. make sure this basic functionality works then add all extras, like looking at the target, etc.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are checking OnUpdate the distance between the cube and the ball rather than simply checking for a collision between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is `OnUpdate()` in `WithinSight` class. When you do the return it never does this `gameObject.tag = "Untagged";`

Change the order of the lines like this.

```
public override TaskStatus OnUpdate() {
    for (int i = 0; i < possibleTargets.Length; ++i) {
        if (withinSight(possibleTargets [i], fieldOfViewAngle)) {
            target.Value = possibleTargets [i];
            gameObject.tag = "Untagged";
            return TaskStatus.Success;
        }
    }
    return TaskStatus.Failure;
}
```

I can't reproduce this scenario, but this code won´t go back to a previuos cube. In case you want that you should save a reference of the last cube the sphere moved towards and do the comparisons in `OnUpdate()` of `WithinSight`.

Comment: I don't know if this will fix the issue stated above, but this is definitely an error that needs fixed.